# php multi language session

Tags: php, session-variables, multilingual

I have been trying for several hours but can't figure this out.  I am trying to make a multi language site, and I have a form to switch the language.  Every time I switch the language, I will have to reload the page twice to see the result.  The site structure is like this:

1: general.php checks if the user is logged in, and store the language in a session variable

```
if($count ==1){
  while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $_SESSION['language'] = $row['language'];               
  }
}
```

2: every page includes header.php which will run the setLanguage function `setLanguage($_SESSION['language'])`

that is in general.php

```
function setLanguage($lan){
  if($lan == "english"){
    include("languages/en.php");
  }elseif($lan == "tra_chinese"){
    include("languages/tra_chinese.php");
  }else{
    include("languages/en.php");
  }
}
```

3: change.php is the page that includes the form to change language.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
$sql = "update users set `language` = :language where `username` = :id";
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute(array(
        ':language'=>$_POST['language'],
        ':id'=>$id
        )
    );
  $_SESSION['language'] = $_POST['language'];
  setLanguage($_SESSION['language']);
}

<form action="change.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="language" value="english" <?php if($_SESSION['language']=='english') echo 'checked="checked"' ?>>English
    <input type="radio" name="language" value="tra_chinese" <?php if($_SESSION['language']=='tra_chinese') echo 'checked="checked"' ?>>中文
    <input style="margin-top:8px" type="submit" value="<?PHP echo CHANGE_LANGUAGE;?>" class="button">
</form>...then goes on to display the contents
```

It appears that the different language file is not loaded the first time I switch the language in change.php.  Could someone please teach me how to fix this?  Thank you!

Comment: Is this code before or after the content is sent to the user?

Comment: all this code is before the content.

Comment: Your form is sent to "password.php" ; why is that ?

Comment: I modified the file name a little bit before posting here.  The form is submitted to itself.  I have corrected it.

Comment: Hello, is my question clear?  Can I explain anything better?  Does any one have any suggestion or solution?  Thanks.